# Text field resets when any action is performed

Tags: java, jsp, validation

I am working on JSP.

The problem I am facing is I have validated a text field in a form. This my jsp code:

```
<div class="input">
    <label for="customerDrCardNumber">
        <fmt:message key="documentSubmission.customerDrCardNumber"/>
    </label>
    <stripes:text id="customerDrCardNumber" name="customerDrCardNumber"/>
</div>
```

and this is my code in action bean:

```
@Validate(on = {"save"},
        required = false,
        minlength = Constants.MIN_CARD_NUMBER,
        maxlength = Constants.MAX_CARD_NUMBER,
        mask = Constants.REGEX_NUMERIC)
private String customerDrCardNumber;
```

If I perform some action in a form like click some button, it deletes the text from drCardNumber textfield. I have passed the param value when I trigger some action but still it deletes the value from the text field.

```
<stripes:param name="customerDrCardNumber" value="${actionBean.customerDrCardNumber}" />
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the value isn't being serialized back to the form. Given that it's only passed back as a variable, there's no reason to expect it to be on the form when it's recreated.

Either save it after you've passed it back and put it back into the form manually, or put a `<form >` around the entire page and let JSP handle the component binding.